# How to quickly cycle through the search history?

Tags: search, highlight

The fact that Vim highlights the strings matched by a search expression can be useful if you are searching for visual patterns in a text.

I would like to now if it was possible to quickly cycle throught the last searches? By that I mean faster that hitting `/` then `<Up>` a given number of time, because the number of time you have to hit `<Up>` grows quadratically with the length of the cycle.

To give an example:
[image]
There is a loop in this gif, but it would be fine if having to go back was necessary.

Comment: Vim doesn't have such a feature. If you can't find a plugin that does that, write it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are entering the search pattern, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to cycle backwards through your search history or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to cycle forwards again. This is explained at the help at `:h c_CTRL-N` ([link](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-N))

Comment: That's better, thanks. However it is still necessary to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enable highlighting.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers if you set incsearch, you should see the highlighting immediately

Comment: on my setup, even after setting incsearch, only the first string matching the result is highlighted

Comment: @GabrielDevillers perhaps the next one does not match?